# Row wise sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below,

```
col1    col2    col3
1        2       3
2        1       3
3        2       1
1        4       6
4        6       1
6        4       1
```

Here I want to sort the record row wise.

Expected output.

```
col1    col2    col3
1        2       3
1        2       3
1        2       3
1        4       6
1        4       6
1        4       6
```

I have used ASCII Values for comparison.

declare @tab table(col1 varchar(10),col2 varchar(10),col3 varchar(20))

```
insert into @tab
select '4','6','1' union
select '6','4','1' union
select '1','2','3'  union
select '2','1','3'  union
select '3','1','2' union
select '4','2','3'  union
select '1','4','6' union

select '5','5','1' union
select '5','5','1' union

select 'a','2','2' union
select '2','a','2' union
select '2','2','a'



;with CTE as(
    Select Case When ascii(Col1) <=  ascii(Col2) And  ascii(Col1) <=  
                     ascii(Col3) Then  cast(Col1 as varchar)
                When ascii(Col2) <=  ascii(Col1) And  ascii(Col2) <=  
                     ascii(Col3) Then  cast(Col2 as varchar)
                Else cast(Col3 as varchar) END as  col1,
                case when ( ascii(col1) >=  ascii(col2) and  ascii(col2) >=  
                            ascii(col3)) or ( ascii(col3) >=  ascii(col2) and  
                            ascii(col2) >=  ascii(col1)) then cast(Col2 as 
                            varchar) 
               when ( ascii(col1) >=  ascii(col3) and  ascii(col3) >=  
                      ascii(col2)) or ( ascii(col2) >=  ascii(col3) and  
                      ascii(col3) >=  ascii(col1)) then  cast(Col3 as varchar)
               when ( ascii(col3) >=  ascii(col1) and  ascii(col1) >=  ascii(col2)) or ( ascii(col2) >=  ascii(col1) and  ascii(col1) >=  ascii(col3)) then cast(Col1 as varchar) end as col2,
                Case When  ascii(Col1) >=  ascii(Col2) And  ascii(Col1) >=  ascii(Col3) Then  cast(Col1 as varchar)
                When  ascii(Col2) >=  ascii(Col1) And  ascii(Col2) >=  ascii(Col3) Then  cast(Col2 as varchar)
                Else  cast(Col3 as varchar) END as col3
    From   @tab)

    select * from CTE
```

Is there any shortest way to achieve this process?

Comment: how this is sorting i mean what is the logic behind ?

Comment: Why a in last row?

Comment: If row 2 started as (2, 7,3) instead of (2,1,3) like it is now, I assume the result should be (2, 3, 7), but which row should it be in final table- still row 2 or at the bottom?

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted.  It is a completely legitimate question.  Just because the answer is "you shouldn't do this" doesn't mean that the question isn't clear and on-topic for the site.

Comment: This seems like a bad design

Answer (score 2):

This need for row-wise sorting is usually a sign that your tables could benefit from a new structure.  What are you really trying to accomplish?  It can probably be better done by normalizing col1, col2, and col3 to look more vertical (this is what the 'unpivoted' CTE is forcing below, but the table should look something like that in the first place).

If you must do this, consider adding a row identifier (basically a primary key) to your table.

```
declare @tab table(
    rowId int identity(1,1),
    col1 varchar(10),
    col2 varchar(10),
    col3 varchar(20)
);

insert @tab values
    ('4','6','1'),
    -- etc
```

Then you can avoid a bunch of case statements and more easily extend to more than just three columns with something like the following:

```
with

    unpivoted as (

        select       rowId, 
                     val,
                     ord = row_number() over(partition by rowId order by val)
        from         @tab
        cross apply  (values (col1), (col2), (col3)) ap (val)

    )

    select    rowId,
              col1 = [1],
              col2 = [2],
              col3 = [3]
    from      unpvioted
    pivot     (max(val) for ord in ([1],[2],[3])) piv
```

You can see it in action [here](https://rextester.com/OSO53901).

Comment: are you a wizard?

Comment: When I use data type as varchar it return the error like "
The type of column "col3" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list."

Comment: Aww thanks @ManfredWippel.  But if you're familiar with pivots and unpivots then this isn't too magical.  Unfortunately, I've worked in environments with severely non-normalized data, so I've used them a lot.

Comment: @Mano, there is another way to unpivot.  I changed to that in my answer.  It's has the same effect except it is less limiting when converting the values for you.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it using `ROW_NUMBER()` like following

```
SELECT (SELECT x 
        FROM   (SELECT  x, 
                             Row_number() 
                               OVER( 
                                 ORDER BY x) rn 
                FROM   (VALUES(col1), 
                              (col2), 
                              (col3))f(x))t 
        WHERE  rn = 1) c1, 
       (SELECT x 
        FROM   (SELECT  x, 
                             Row_number() 
                               OVER( 
                                 ORDER BY x) rn 
                FROM   (VALUES(col1), 
                              (col2), 
                              (col3))f(x))t 
        WHERE  rn = 2) c2, 
       (SELECT x 
        FROM   (SELECT  x, 
                             Row_number() 
                               OVER( 
                                 ORDER BY x) rn 
                FROM   (VALUES(col1), 
                              (col2), 
                              (col3))f(x))t 
        WHERE  rn = 3) c3 
FROM   @table
```

OR using nested `CTE` like following.

```
  ;WITH cte1 
     AS (SELECT (SELECT Min(f) 
                 FROM   (VALUES (col1), 
                                (col2), 
                                (col3)) AS Fields(f)) m1, 
                * 
         FROM   @table), 
     cte2 
     AS (SELECT (SELECT COALESCE(Min(f), M1) AS M2
                 FROM   (VALUES (col1), 
                                (col2), 
                                (col3)) AS Fields(f) 
                 WHERE  f > m1) m2, 
                * 
         FROM   cte1), 
     cte3 
     AS (SELECT m1, 
                m2, 
                (SELECT COALESCE(Min(f),m2) as m3 
                 FROM   (VALUES (col1), 
                                (col2), 
                                (col3)) AS Fields(f) 
                 WHERE  f > m2) m3 
         FROM   cte2) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte3
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/HWVT92724)

Comment: This is return null values in some of the column.

Comment: Please insert one row like '5','1','5'

Comment: You can check the updated query here .. https://rextester.com/STKZ87454

Answer (score 0):

use case when like below

```
select case when col1>col2>col3 then col1
        when col2>col3 then col2
        else col3 end as col1, -- this is the condition for first column
```

you have to write this way for 3columns

Answer (score 0):

If all columns are Integer type then the below query will works,

```
SELECT c1 = CASE
  WHEN c1 <= c2 AND c1 <= c3 THEN c1
  WHEN c2 <= c1 AND c2 <= c3 THEN c2
  ELSE c3 END,
c2 = CASE 
  WHEN c1 <= c2 AND c1 <= c3 THEN 
    CASE WHEN c2 <= c3 THEN c2 ELSE c3 END
  WHEN c2 <= c1 AND c2 <= c3 THEN
    CASE WHEN c1 <= c3 THEN c1 ELSE c3 END
  ELSE
    CASE WHEN c1 <= c2 THEN c1 ELSE c2 END
  END,
c3 = CASE
  WHEN c1 >= c2 AND c1 >= c3 THEN c1
  WHEN c2 >= c1 AND c2 >= c3 THEN c2
  ELSE c3 END
FROM temp_x;
```

If any character then you can use ASCII value to cpompare.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is likely to be `case` expressions, but that doesn't generalize.

I would go for `apply` as a good balance between performance and scalability:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then col end) as col1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then col end) as col2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then col end) as col3             
      from (select v.*,
                   row_number() over (order by col) as seqnum
            from (values (t.col1), (t.col2), (t.col3)) v(col)
           ) v
     ) v;
```

This can also readily handle `NULL` values and ties, which greatly complicate a `case` approach.